# How does choosing a Borel subgroup $B$ of a Lie group $G$ determine a set of positive roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Say we have a Torus subgroup $T$ in a Lie subgroup $G$. The Lie algebra of $T$ is a Cartan subalgebra of the Lie algebra of $G$ and hence gives us a root space decomposition. Is it true that choosing a maximum solvable connected (Borel) subgroup that contains $T$ determines a labeling of the roots in the root space decomposition as positive or negative? Can somebody can me some insight into why this is? Thank you

Comment: Have you seen the notion of an "abstract" Cartan subalgebra? I found a mention in Chriss-Ginzburg p137 (what follows is a condensation of that). Since for any two Borel subalgebras $\mathfrak{b}, \mathfrak{b}'$ there is a (canonical) isomorphism $\mathfrak{b}/[\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{b}] \cong \mathfrak{b}'/[\mathfrak{b}', \mathfrak{b}']$, then (remembering that all Borels are conjugate to each other), you can define the "abstract Cartan subalgebra" by identifying all these quotient spaces.

Comment: The abstract Cartan is (non-canonically) isomorphic to the original choice of Cartan $\mathfrak{h}$, since you have to choose an initial Borel $B$ for which $\mathfrak{b} \supset \mathfrak{h}$. But once you've done so, by considering the weights of the $\mathfrak{h}$-action on $\mathfrak{b}$, you effectively get a choice of positive roots.

Comment: I realised maybe that is a bit too overpowered for what needs to be answered. Maybe it would help to realise that the set of Borel subgroups corresponds one-to-one with the set of bases of the root system defined by $\mathfrak{h}$. I'm quite sure that this is an elementary result in Lie theory, and can be found in the usual textbooks (maybe Humphreys?) - I'll try and find a reference.